# Create a new color from two RGB values

Tags: rgb, livecode

Is it possible to combine two `RGB` values to create another color in `livecode`?

Example:

`First color: (0,0,255) //BLUE`

`Second color: (255,0,0) //RED`

In this case, I would like to store the result of the two colors into a variable.

Let's say, `put "0, 0, 255" + "255, 0, 0" into CombinedColors`

Comment: So you want to end up with `(255, 0, 255)`? And what about adding `(0, 0, 255)` twice? You can't go beyond 255 for a single channel in RGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear how you want to combine the colours. If you want to blend the colours, you might simply add them.

```
put 255,0,0 into myRed
put 0,0,255 into myBlue
put 0,10,100 into myGreen
repeat with x = 1 to 3
  put min(item x of myRed + item x of myBlue + item x of myGreen,255) into \
    item x of myNewColor
end repeat
```

The formula I'm using here doesn't make much sense. If you can more specific in your question, I'll be able to adjust my answer with a better formula.

You may also use weighted values:

```
put min(.333*item x of myRed + .333*item x of myBlue + .334*item \
        x of myGreen,255) into item x of myNewColor
```

You can adjust the weights to make the blend appear more natural. (This example is with 3 colours, to demonstrate the weights).

Comment: I think what I am looking is the `weighted values`. I added `round` to make it work:  `put min(the round of(.333*item x of tCurColor + .333*item x of tColor),255) into \
               item x of newColor`. Thanks for the help Mark.

Answer (score 1):

For combining 2 colours using RGB values, there are 2 ways.

1. If you need a lighter texture, the formulae you need to use is 
   `(r1, g1, b1) + (r2, g2, b2) =
   (min(r1+r2, 255), min(g1+g2, 255), min(b1+b2, 255))`
2. If you need a slightly darker texture , use 
   `(r1, g1, b1) + (r2, g2, b2) =
   ((r1 + r2) / 2, (g1 + g2) / 2, (b1 + b2) / 2)`

Or if you just want to avoid the hassle , use this simple online tools http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/color-blend/

Comment: Just wondering if I can add another color into the mixture. Is it still possible?

Comment: You can do anything with the new RGB .

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around these steps.

Comment: The link to the "on-line tool" really doesn't make sense for a programming question.